# Apollo-client load and merge data from server seamlessly

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Looking at the sample code: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/mutations/

Lets say login form mutation returns the JWT token and also the user **profile**. Is there a way to save the user profile to client cache so we can display the "home" page with this data immediately?

In other words, as we are already going to the server to authenticate, server return the data to start to display something straight away to the user.

I don't want to write purely client-side data such as `isLoggedIn`. I would like to write the whole **profile data** in a way the Home page can read from cache or server as we usually do with `useQuery(...)`

Comment: do you have cache initialized and configured with apollo-client for your application?

Comment: yes, I am using `InMemoryCache`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's simple.

```
  const client = useApolloClient();

  const [loginUser, { loading }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    onCompleted(result) {
      const membership = _.get(result, 'loginUser.`profile`');
      const loginUserResult = _.get(result, 'loginUser');

      sessionStorage.setItem(
        'auth', '...'
      );
      client.writeData({ data: { profile } });
    },
  });
```

Then when home page renders, profile data is available in local cache and graphql doesn't make another request for profile